# NGXS: ofActionSuccessful not being triggered however the action shows on Redux Devtools

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I am following the caching example from [docs](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/recipes/cache). My Action first looks up the existing store, before fetching via `http` call. The `ofActionSuccesful` successfully triggers when I call http, but doesn't triggers when when returning from the store. Here is my store code

```
  @Action(Get)
  get(ctx: StateContext<SubmissionStateModel>, action: Get) {
    const id = action.payload;
    const submissions = ctx.getState().submissions;
    const index = submissions.findIndex(submission => parseInt(submission.id, 10) === parseInt(id, 10));

    return index > -1
      ? ctx.dispatch(new GetSuccess(submissions[index]))
      : this._submissionService.get(id).pipe(
          map(response => {
            ctx.patchState({ submissions: [response, ...submissions] });
            return ctx.dispatch(new GetSuccess(response));
          }),
        );
  }
```

and from my component

```
      this._actions
        .pipe(
          ofActionSuccessful(SubmissionActions.GetSuccess),
          takeUntil(this._onDestroy$),
        )
        .subscribe(action => {
          this._store.dispatch(new SubmissionActions.SetActive(action.payload.id));
          this.submissionEditForm.patchValue(action.payload);
        });
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `map(..)` to `switchMap(...)`?

Comment: The maping to response work. It doesn't work for the first case, i.e. we found the `submission` in our existing store.

Comment: I have even tried creating the observable for my first case like `of(submissions[index]).pipe(map(submission => ctx.dispatch(new GetSuccess(submission))))`

Comment: Why are you using a `map()` operator? This will not chain the actions. You should use a `switchMap()` so that the store knows it's a child action.

Comment: switched to `switchMap` but my problem remains. I am still not able to get `ofActionType(GetSuccesful)` when returning from `of(submissions[index]).pipe(switchMap(submission => ctx.dispatch(new GetSuccess(submission))))`

Comment: Very strange. You can try logging everything it to see what's happening `this._actions.subscribe(a=>console.log(a))`.

Comment: console is empty for the `get from store` condition, for `http`, i get two states of action, dispatched & successful. Let me try doing it without ternary operator.

Comment: nopse, doesn't help by switching to `if/else` verbosity.

Comment: can you try using `store.dispatch(new GetSuccess(response))` instead of `ctx.dispatch()`. The `ctx.dispatch()` is for current context and I'm not sure if it's safe to use it after an async operation, because the context has changed.

Comment: i probably would have bought into that if the http call wasnt working, but it is. having said that, i did do store.dispatch, same results. http call works, but looking up existing store doesn't.

Comment: I have seen ngxs silently hide errors thrown inside actions. I once spent days trying to find a bug only to find that an error was being thrown but was hidden. So everything looked like it should be working when it wasn't. I think this might be happening here. An error is interrupting the action from appearing in the actions observable.

Comment: how did you go about figuring out that error?

Comment: lol. on first click, it doesn't catch the action, i go back, click on any other submission, the action subscriber starts to work.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update, I was able to solve this one. The `actions` subscriber need to be inside constructor. I was initialising it in `ngOnInit`. The final code looks like this

```
  constructor(
    private _actions: Actions,
  ) {
    this._actions
      .pipe(
        ofActionSuccessful(SubmissionActions.GetSuccess),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy$),
      )
      .subscribe(action => {
        this._store.dispatch(new SubmissionActions.SetActive(action.payload.id));
        this.submissionEditForm.patchValue(action.payload);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Action subscriber does not necessarily have to be defined in the constructor. You can define them anywhere in your code - of course also in `ngOnInit`.
You just have to make sure that an action subscriber is defined before you call the dispatch method of your store with the respective store command.